# Use image from private repo in Jupyterhub

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, jupyterhub

I'm trying to insert my own jupyter image into jupyterhub. With helm I have set up jupyterhub to run locally with minikube with the default image:

```sh
RELEASE=jhub
NAMESPACE=jhub

helm upgrade --cleanup-on-fail \
  --install $RELEASE jupyterhub/jupyterhub \
  --namespace $NAMESPACE \
  --create-namespace \
  --version=0.9.0 \
  --values config.yaml
```

This works.

Then I try to change the image by modifying the config.yaml:

```yaml
singleuser:
    image:
        name: myrepo.azurecr.io/myrepo/myimage
        tag: 1.0
    imagePullSecret:
        enabled: true
        name: mysecret
```

This should point out my image on my private repository. `mysecret` is a secret created with `kubectl create secret docker-registry mysecret ...` However, when running above `helm upgrade` command I get an error that seem to be caused by the jupyterhub helm chart not being able to handle the named `imagePullSecret` properly:

```sh
Error: UPGRADE FAILED: failed to create resource: Secret "singleuser-image-credentials" is invalid: data[.dockerconfigjson]: Invalid value: "<secret contents redacted>": invalid character ',' looking for beginning of value
```

If I add `--dry-run --debug` to my `helm upgrade` command I get a hint of the problem:

```yaml
kind: Secret
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: singleuser-image-credentials
  labels:
    component: singleuser-image-credentials
    app: jupyterhub
    release: jhub
    chart: jupyterhub-0.9.0
    heritage: Helm
type: kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson
data:
  .dockerconfigjson: ewogICJhdXRocyI6IHsKICAgICJodHRwczovL2luZGV4LmRvY2tlci5pby92MS8iOiB7CiAgICAgICJ1c2VybmFtZSI6ICwKICAgICAgInBhc3N3b3JkIjogLAogICAgICAiYXV0aCI6ICJQRzVwYkQ0NlBHNXBiRDQ9IgogICAgfQogIH0KfQ==
```

The dockerconfigjson secret above doesn't actually contain the secret:

```sh
$ echo ewogICJhdXRocyI6IHsKICAgICJodHRwczovL2luZGV4LmRvY2tlci5pby92MS8iOiB7CiAgICAgICJ1c2VybmFtZSI6ICwKICAgICAgInBhc3N3b3JkIjogLAogICAgICAiYXV0aCI6ICJQRzVwYkQ0NlBHNXBiRDQ9IgogICAgfQogIH0KfQ== | base64 --decode
{
  "auths": {
    "https://index.docker.io/v1/": {
      "username": ,
      "password": ,
      "auth": "PG5pbD46PG5pbD4="
    }
  }
}
$ echo PG5pbD46PG5pbD4= | base64 --decode
<nil>:<nil>
```

## Question

This kind of looks like a bug. But there should be some way to insert the credentials into jupyterhub 0.9.0 using a secret?

## Workaround:

I can insert the username and password directly with `helm upgrade --set singleuser.imagePullSecret.password=<my password here> ...`. Then it works.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding your private helm repository to `config.yaml` you should modify `values.yaml` file as mentioned in [this github issue](https://github.com/jupyterhub/zero-to-jupyterhub-k8s/issues/1465#issuecomment-714739873):

```
  image:
    name: <image>
    tag: '<tag>'
    pullPolicy: Always
    pullSecrets:
      - secretName: "<secret-name>"
```